# error: protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Tags: swift

I made a sample using Protocol and Generic.
The function foo() wants to receive protocol as argument, but an error is occurring.
`error: protocol 'SimpleProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Could you tell me how to solve it?
Please give me some advice.

```swift
protocol SimpleProtocol {
    associatedtype MyType
    func doSomething()
}

struct SimpleA<T>: SimpleProtocol {
    typealias MyType = T
    
    func doSomething() {
        // do something...
    }
}

struct SimpleB<T>: SimpleProtocol {
    typealias MyType = T
    
    func doSomething() {
        // do something...
    }
}

class Sample {
    func debugMethod() {
        let simpleA = SimpleA<Int>()
        let simpleB = SimpleB<Double>()
        
        foo(simpleA)
        foo(simpleB)
    }

    // error: protocol 'SimpleProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
    func foo(_ simple: SimpleProtocol) {
        simple.doSomething()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```swift
class Sample {
    func debugMethod() {
        let simpleA = SimpleA<Int>()
        let simpleB = SimpleB<Double>()
        
        foo(simpleA)
        foo(simpleB)
    }
    
    func foo<P: SimpleProtocol>(_ simple: P) {
        simple.doSomething()
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3569109 You are only supposed to ask one question at a time and certainly not add more questions _after_ the original question has been answered.

Comment: @Omid, please add a better explanation to your answer. Code only answers are discouraged.